# ng-click not working for dynamically inserted html got from the http.get call in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

Hi I am using angular js for my php project. I am using ngclick for anchor link which is like this

```
<a href="http://localhost/mediaads/signup" ng-click="showregister($event)">Don't have an account? Create One</a>
```

when clicks on the link i will call method showregister in controller and replace the html by calling http get method.

```
$http.get(baseUrl+'signup').success(function(res){$(elem).replaceWith(res);})
```

res is the html data and again it has ng click in the html

Dynamically got html data has again ng clicks in them. Those ng clicks are not working

Can anyone tell me how to make ngclick work for dynamic elements.

Comment: You need to have the ng-click's functions defined in your javascript. Also make sure after the dom is inserted you are calling a rebind on the dom with `$scope.$apply()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML that is added dynamically like this must manually be linked with a scope.

To do this inject and use the `$compile` service:

```
$http.get(baseUrl + 'signup').success(function(res) {
  $(elem).replaceWith($compile(res)($scope));
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/E0neYHsVnmHKn7goLqL4?p=preview

Comment: What if my html is insert on page load?

Comment: How do you mean? Can you show an example in Plunker?