# Toggle content using ng-click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click, ng-hide

I have the following query which loops through an array of strings `wikiContent`. Once I show the first three values (sentences) from the array, I want to add a link that says `More` and when you click on it it shows the rest of the sentences.

Here is what I have (this is inside an `AJAX` request using `$http`):

```
var opt = "<span>";
for(var j = 0; j < wikiContent.length; j++){
    opt += wikiContent[j];
    if(j === 2){
        opt += "</span><span ng-hide='!show'>";
    }
}
opt += " ... <a href=\"\" ng-click='show=!show'>More</a>";
opt += "</span>";

$rootScope.text = opt;
```

When I click on `More`, it does 2 things:

- It reloads the page.
- It doesn't toggle the text

What can I do to fix both of these issues?

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="panel-body" ng-bind-html="toHtml(text)"></div>
```

Here is the `toHtml()` function:

```
$scope.toHtml = function(string){
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(string);
};
```

Comment: You an empty href in there. You may need to add `#` or `javascript:;` or use a button. You can also stop propagation like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20300866/angularjs-ng-click-stoppropagation).

Comment: That stops the reload, but it doesn't fix the toggle of the span.

Comment: Is `ng-click` running? Can you alert the value of `show` in the `ng-click` to test?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't look like `ng-click` is running. No alert box displayed. I think it has something to do with dynamically adding the html...

Comment: Do you get any errors?  [empty `href` should prevent a page reload](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/docs/api/ng/directive/a)

Comment: @ExplosionPills I don't get any errors. It goes to the root page: http://nebala.com/search/google

Comment: With dynamic html in Angular you would need to add a `$compile` and get it into the `$scope`. [Check out this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27838634/ng-click-not-working-for-dynamically-inserted-html-got-from-the-http-get-call-in) to see if it helps.

Comment: makes sense, but I am not really sure how to add that to what I have...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documents, Angular mentioned that it is a bad idea to work with the dom from your controllers:

> Note: This error often means that you are accessing DOM from your controllers, which is usually a sign of poor coding style that violates separation of concerns.

So, what I did was create an includes directory and putting included stuff in there and now I am using `ng-include` instead of building the dom items in the controller.